# Using Google Apps Script to set the correct answer in a Google Forms (that has been defined as a quiz)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I am trying to use Google Apps Script to set the correct answer in a Google Forms (that has been defined as a quiz)

The actual Google Form can be defined using code such as

```
var form = FormApp.create('New Form');
var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?');
item.setChoices([
        item.createChoice('Ketchup'),
        item.createChoice('Mustard'),
        item.createChoice('Relish')
    ]);
```

(Taken from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

Is there any way **in code** to define what actually the right answer is and to assign it points?

I know this can be done manually...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> UPDATE: On April 2017 Google [announced](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/create-quizzes-in-google-forms-with.html) that now it's possible to create Google Forms quizzes programmatically.

---

At this time there isn't a method to set the correct answer. Please star the issue [6143](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6143): Create Quiz Form via API

Comment: TextItem doesn't support this API https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117437423

Answer (score -1):

Copy

```
6.// Make a 10 point question and set up the question
7.    const item = form.addCheckboxItem();
8.    item.setTitle("What flavors are in neapolitan ice cream?");
9.    item.setPoints(10);
11.// chocolate, vanilla, & strawberry are the correct answers
12.   item.setChoices([
13.     item.createChoice("chocolate", true),
14.     item.createChoice("vanilla", true),
15.     item.createChoice("rum raisin", false),
16.     item.createChoice("strawberry", true),
17.     item.createChoice("mint", false)
18.   ]);
```