# Set correct answer in key of Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-form-quiz

I am wanting to set the value of a Answer Key to a specific quiz item using google app scripts.
Looking through the docs, I could not find what I was looking for.

I can programmatically generate random questions, but need to now programmatically set the answer using a google forms- quiz.

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i in items) { 
    Logger.log(items[i].getTitle() + ': ' + items[i].getId());
  }
  var force1 = 10 + (Math.round(Math.random()*10));
  var distance1 = 10 + (Math.round(Math.random()*10));
  items[1].setTitle(' (W1)  Given a force of ' + force1 + ', and a displacement of ' + distance1 + '.  What is the value of Work?');

  //Generate correct answer by quiz item variables
  //Set correct answer to quiz item 1

  //When the student clicks submit, the quiz is graded on the correct answers generated and set by the google app scripts.
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Google Apps Script to set the correct answer in a Google Forms (that has been defined as a quiz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603541/using-google-apps-script-to-set-the-correct-answer-in-a-google-forms-that-has-b)

Answer (score -1):

textItem `validation` and `validationBuilder` seem to be the things you need.
Here is an example from the [Apps script docs:](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-validation-builder)

```
// Add a text item to a form and require it to be a number within a range.
var textItem = form.addTextItem().setTitle('Pick a number between 1 and 100?');
var textValidation = FormApp.createTextValidation()
  .setHelpText(“Input was not a number between 1 and 100.”)
  .requireNumberBetween(1, 100);
textItem.setValidation(textValidation);
```

Comment: The question is about Google Forms quizzes. `validation` isn't what the OP is asking for.